# Which TLD would be suited to a personal site?

Tags: domains, top-level-domains

I'm planning what is essentially a "business card" website for myself, and have been looking at domains. My primary site (a `.com`) is for my blog and portfolio and the like, but I want a separate site for basic information, contact, networks, and the like.

In this light, there are a few TLDs that seem to be suitable: `.info`, `.me`, and `.name`.

I'd appreciate remarks on the differences between these options, and suggestion on which would be suitable for my need.

Comment: @RandomBen I don't know about that, I think this question could have a concrete answer.

Comment: @Grant, the only technical difference between the three is the TLD.   Answers as to what is 'best' ask for experience, which broadly depends on just how well any given site was constructed and promoted. Non CW answers should contain something that can be reproduced step by step, and I really don't see that possibility here. I'm making this CW.

Comment: "Non CW answers should contain something that can be reproduced step by step" Really? I don't find that rationale compelling. There are criteria for making items community wiki, but I don't know of criteria for non-community wiki questions other than "ask an on-topic question." The whole notion of everything going community wiki I feel undermines the incentives for contributing to the site. Community wiki-ing a question means "this question has less value, so we are eliminating the normal incentives we use to get contributions."

Comment: @artlung - @Grant - meta is a better place for this discussion :)

Comment: Perhaps the incentive should be: how can I phrase this question, such that it will only receive one valid answer. And as @Tim says: if you disagree, perhaps you should start a Meta discussion about it :)

Comment: http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/231/why-is-this-question-community-wiki

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**.info**

> The name is derived from information
>   indicating that the domain is intended
>   for informative Internet resources,
>   although registration requirements do
>   not prescribe any theme orientation.

**.me**

You're in [Montenegro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.me)? Seriously, I am not a fan of using other country codes for other uses. I don't like things whose legal jurisdiction is not my own.

**.name**

> It is intended for use by individuals
>   for representation of their personal
>   names, nicknames, screen names,
>   pseudonyms, or other types of
>   identification labels.

I think `.name` is the most appropriate one to use.

That said, the one that's easiest to remember and communicate to people is always going to be best. I like `.com` and `.org` best for personal sites.

But to each his or her own. The original intent of TLDs has been subverted over the years, people do as they please. Use the one *you like* the best.

Comment: Huh, I didn't know that `.me` was a country TLD. I could have sworn I'd seen that TLD before on other personal sites, and took it to mean "me, myself, and I"

Comment: Interestingly, the Wikipedia article includes this tidbit: "Trying to position itself for global use, and become a personal namespace like `.name`: can be registered and used for any purpose."

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for: it described the meaning of each TLD, and recommended one given my criteria.

Comment: how to find out which registrar registers a .lad domain ?
my last name is lad and i would love to have my own firstname.lad domain

Comment: @kindrudekid There does not appear to be a TLD in the IANA Root Zone Database: http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/ for Ladonia ( http://www.ladonia.net/ ). It appears you are out of luck.

Answer (score 7):

About 10 years ago I chose .net for my mine. I'm not selling anything so I'm not a .com and I'm not an organization in any way so I'm not a .org.

Newer TLDs like .name seem like a good choice as well. .me is good as long as Montenegro doesn't change their minds about their TLD.

Comment: You're also not a network service provider (ISP etc.).

Answer (score 4):

The cheapest one to buy. :)

Answer (score 2):

I would use .in. As it ends your name, and if its a personal site it could lead to an interesting card.

GrantPal.in

Check this for my meaning:

> http://www.smus.com/minimal-business-card-design/

Comment: I don't know about that. If you're going to be putting it on a business card, then it needs to be instantly recognisable as a domain nane. If I saw `grantpal.in` on a business card, I wouldn't instantly recognise it as a domain name. And if I did, I'd think you were an indian... (maybe you are? In which case, go for it)

Comment: Interesting idea, using a country TLD in such a way. However, I'm neither a native of, nor resident in, India :) @Farseeker's remark on recognizability also gives me pause.

Comment: @Farseeker @Grant That is why I linked that card. I'm not Indian, I just thought it would be an interesting usage.

Comment: @MarkHenderson one solution to make it instantly recognisable as a domain name is to add https:// at the front: `https://GrantPal.in`. This works when the domain is written as on a business card, but not when spoken. Though, when the domain name is spoken typically the person doing the speaking can elaborate on the fact that it is a domain name.

Answer (score 2):

If you're in Australia, there's `.id.au`. Like all `.au` domains, every single one is vetted before being assigned to you. I tried to get a `.id.au` domain for myself once and was refused because the one I chose "was not a close enough likeness to your real identity".

Your milage may vary.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is quite old, but...

Even though it is for personal use, if available I'd stick with .com - and if not available, the other members of the Big Three (.net or .org).  Or any suitable local ccTLD.

Personally, I'd avoid .info or .name because (sadly) it seems the majority of users of these domains are spam-houses.

As others have commented, I'm not a huge fan of using ccTLDs for general use, although .tv .ws and .me have become widespread.

But I'm also aware of the problems caused a few years back when the Government of Columbia revoked most .co domains overnight, and without warning.  The .co ccTLD had been operated by one of the Universities ([the story is on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.co)). So *caveat emptor* if you chose to use a domain outside of its official purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I really think that using your .com is the best solution if you are U.S based, however the other TLD's should be just fine if you are using it appropriately and respecting the Countries laws.  My opinion.